# Get Properties From Expression Func

Tags: c#, html, generics, expression, extension-methods

I have an extension method that outputs HTML for a date range picker.

```
public static MvcHtmlString InputGroupDateRangePickerFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) where TProperty : IDateRange
```

This extension method has a generic property `TProperty` that has a `IDateRange` constraint. The `IDateRange` interface has a `From` and `To` property.

I want to be able to access each of the `IDateRange` properties like so:

```
var html = $"<div class=\"input-daterange input-group\">
     {htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression.From)}
     {htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression.To)}</div>";
```

As the `expression` parameter is an Expression Func I can not access these properties.

I initially had two Expression Parameters, one for the `From` property and the other for the `To` property.

```
Html.InputGroupDateRangePickerFor(x => x.Search.From, x => x.Search.To)
```

But I want to only have to pass in a `IDateRange` object like so

```
Html.InputGroupDateRangePickerFor(x => x.Search.DateRange)
```

Comment: Why do you have an `Expression<Func>` and no `Func`?

Comment: I just mimicked the TextBoxFor parameters

Answer (score 1):

Could use an editor template instead:

**Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateRange.cshtml**

```
@model Services.Models.DateRange

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m, new { @class = "m-b-none" })
        @Html.DescriptionFor(m => m)
        <div class="input-daterange input-group" style="width: 100%;">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.From, new{@class="form-control"})
            <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.To, new{@class="form-control"})
            <div class="input-group-addon validation-addon"><i class="fa fa-check-circle green-text validation"></i></div>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m, null, new { @class = "validation-message" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SearchCriteria.ExpectedDateOfDecisionRange)
```

Or to keep usage consistent with your other extensions you could wrap this in a function:

```
[StringFormatMethod("format")]
public static MvcHtmlString FormGroupDateRangePickerFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string format = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") where TProperty : IDateRange
{
    var html = $"{htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression)}";
    return new MvcHtmlString(html);
}
```

So usage remains as:

```
@Html.FormGroupDateRangePickerFor(x => x.SearchCriteria.ExpectedDateOfDecisionRange)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by grabbing the expression body and then using it to create From and To expression strings. I then used the method `GetExpressionValue` to get the `IDateRange` values.

```
var expressionBody = expression.Body.ToString().Split(new[] { '.' }, 2)[1];

var fromExpressionBody = $"{expressionBody}.{nameof(IDateRange.From)}";
var toExpressionBody = $"{expressionBody}.{nameof(IDateRange.To)}";

var dateRangeValues = GetExpressionValue(htmlHelper, expression);
```

I then used these variables in to generate the HTML.

```
var html = $"<div class=\"input-daterange input-group\">
     {htmlHelper.TextBox(fromExpressionBody, dateRangeValues.From)}
     {htmlHelper.TextBox(toExpressionBody, dateRangeValues.To)}</div>";
```